# XCode 5 in app purchase issue

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios7, xcode5, storekit, xcode4.6.3

On Xcode 4.6.3 this delegate method below works good:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest*)aRequest didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse*)response;
```

But when I try to run the same project on Xcode 5 it does not work. Instead of invoke delegate method above the app calls this method:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

I have description of error:

```
{NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

I use standard iOS 7 simulator and Xcode 5 but in this case the logic does not work as I expect.

For version 4.6.3 all work

Comment: What happens when you test it on a device instead of the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment is actually the answer, further digging shows Apple doc for Xcode 5 release notes says under the iOS Simulator section

> StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241)

Comment: yep, there are many few bad issues also about playing video. so there is no alternative as I think.

Comment: I see the same error on my iPad. It happened with the already released app after the switch to Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in another post, even if it's not the desidered behavior of the question, you can still test IAP from Simulator & Xcode5 if you  deploy and run/test for iOS6 (with test user, sandbox environment, etc...).

For me, this solution is better than deploy on device in early staging of developing phase.

Mick.